# Process login at same time with spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, primefaces

I have a web application, which is done with Primefaces 6.0 - Spring Security 3.0 - Spring 4.0, HDIV, and mybatis.
My problem is with Login, when i do login with spring security with user A, its succesfully proccessed by spring and loads user A information.
When I do login user A, B, C and D, at same time, each users are succesfully proccessed by spring BUT, user A loads user A information, user B loads user C information, user C loads user C information and user D loads user D information.
What could be the problem?

What do I do with the code below is to let Spring Security do the authentication. That method is in my ManagedBean with `@ViewScoped` and it's called from the .xhtml

```java
public void procesarLogin() {
try {
        Authentication requestToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
            getLoginForm().getJ_username(), getLoginForm().getJ_password());
        try {
        Authentication authenticationResponseToken
            = authenticationManager.authenticate(requestToken);
        SecurityContext sc = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
        sc.setAuthentication(authenticationResponseToken);
        if (authenticationResponseToken.isAuthenticated()) {
            sc.setAuthentication(authenticationResponseToken);
            SessionUtil.setSessionAttribute(HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT_KEY, sc);
            authSuccessHandler.onAuthenticationSuccess(FacesUtil.getRequest(),
                FacesUtil.getResponse(), authenticationResponseToken);
        }
        } catch (BadCredentialsException | LockedException
            | DisabledException badCredentialsException) {
        logger.error("error", badCredentialsException);
        FacesUtil.errorMessage("Falló autenticación, verifique su usuario, contraseña o el estado de su cuenta");
        } catch (ServletException | IOException ex) {
        logger.error("error", ex);
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(LoginView.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
        logger.error("", e);
    }
}
```

```xml
<p:commandButton id="btnIniciarSesion" style="width: 100%;padding-top: 5px;padding-bottom: 5px;"
                 class="btn btn-primary" ajax="false"
                 actionListener="#{loginBean.procesarLogin()}" 
                 value="Iniciar sesión"/>
```

Comment: *"user B loads user C information"* Where is the code that does the *loading*? Perhaps the error is there, or in the database you're loading from.

Comment: I mean, from database user B loads user B... but in SecurityContextHolder spring puts the User C Context to user B

Comment: provide complete spring security configuration, provide the authentication code (DAO) and also screen shot of your user table.

Comment: check whether B and C principal(username) in your table is duplicate?

Comment: Then you must be keeping state somewhere that leaks into other threads, aka your code isn't thread-safe.

Comment: How do you test the multiple concurrent logins?